# knockout binding out of model object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, dojo

I have a layer and map object in javascript, and I am using knockoutjs.

```
var layer1 = new Layer("http://layeraddress1",{
                "id":"layer1",
                "visible":ko.observable(true)
            });

var layer2 = new Layer("http://layeraddress2",{
                "id":"layer2",
                "visible":ko.observable(true)
            });

var layersViewModel = {
            layers: [
                     {"layer": layer1, },
                     {"layer": layer2, }
                    ]
        }
 ko.applyBindings(layersViewModel, document.getElementById("layersContainer"))
```

and I am binding the layers UI lke this. I used `ko.observable()` out of the **layersViewModel** .

```
<div id="layersContainer">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: layers">
        <li>
           <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: layer.visible"/>
           <span data-bind="text: layer.id"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when I run code, checkbox is checked. But when I unchecked the checkbox, it does not effect layer visibility1.
I want to change layer1 and layer2 visibiliity via checkbox checked.

I tell you shortly here and I prepared main [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/firtinalim/dtXUG/6/) code here.

Comment: Where do you use the `visible` binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) in your html? I don't see it in your sample?

Comment: You're using the `checked` binding in your checkbox. You're not not using the `visible` binding anywhere.

Comment: I want to change layer1 and layer2 visibiliity via checkbox checked.